# How convert string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Lets say we have the string `'\342\200\231'` (same as `"\\342\\200\\231"`). What is a quick way to convert this string to `"\342\200\231"` (same as `’` Unicode character)?

Comment: So, you want to convert any leading and trailing single-quotes to double-quotes? Or all single-quotes to double-quotes?

Comment: Is the `'` part of the actual string? Or are you trying to convert a single-quoted string into a double-quoted string (they're both the same thing, aside from double-quoted strings allowing more things like interpolation)?

Comment: No, quote is not a part of string. If you paste both strings into irb you can make idea what I need.

Comment: Then state more clearly what kind of transformation you want to perform on the string.

Comment: You are asking how to turn a 12-character string into a 3-character string, right?  If so, great question!

Comment: Yes that is exactly your point, right?  You start with `'\342\200\231'`, a 12-character string that is not interpolated because it contains raw backslashes and you want to end up with `"\342\200\231"` in which interpolation takes place leaving you with a 3-character string.  That is how I read your question.  Am I wrong?  Of course it is really 1-character because this 3-byte sequence is UTF-8 :)

Comment: Yes, you got idea right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposal:

```
s.gsub(/\\(\d{3})/) { $1.oct.chr }
```

It depends on what assumptions you can make about your input.

Comment: Thanks, this is safer than eval solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be asking is how to change a 12-character string into a three-character string.

```
'\342\200\231'
```

is 12 characters long.

```
"\342\200\231"
```

is three characters long; actually three bytes long, but in Ruby 1.8 it is about the same since strings are sequences of bytes anyway.

Here is an **EVIL** answer for you (you did say quick), which takes advantage of `eval` to do your "parsing":

```
irb(main):017:0> s = '\342\200\231'
=> "\\342\\200\\231"
irb(main):018:0> t = eval('"' + s + '"')
=> "\342\200\231"
irb(main):019:0> s.length
=> 12
irb(main):020:0> t.length
=> 3
```

Sorry for the eval!

I should probably give a more helpful answer...  **EDIT**: Someone else just did.

Comment: Thanks! Don't like eval, but this is nice and short solution.